# Have code execute after call to async function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, curl, httpclient

I have a async void function that I call to execute a couple curl calls. I have code that needs to execute after that function is executed as a variable is set inside the function. Right now it looks like the code is executed before the async function. Any suggestions?

```
Update(allNumbers, allValues);

//result is a global variable that is set inside the Update function.

if (result.Contains("success"))
{
    message.InnerText = "Result: " + result + "\r\nSuccessfully updated value";
}
else
{
    message.InnerText = "Result: " + result + "\r\nError updating value";
}


async void Update(List<string> allNumbers, List<string> allValues){
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
    string file = "";
    HttpRequestMessage response = new HttpRequestMessage();
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri('Web IP');
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));                   
            try
            {
                file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "user.xml");
                response = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 'Web Extension 1');
                response.Content = new StringContent(file, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                await client.SendAsync(response).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri('Web IP' + 'Web Extension 1');
                    IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
                    foreach (Cookie the_cookie in responseCookies)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(path + "sessionid.txt", String.Empty);
                        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path + "sessionid.txt", true))
                            {                                    
                                // Create file with cookie information                                                     
                            }                               
                        }
                    });                        
                }                    
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    using (var stw = new StreamWriter(path + "error.txt", true))
                    {
                        stw.WriteLine("Error with Login cURL Call - " + ex.ToString() + "\r\n---------------------------------------------------");
                    }  
                    result = "Error with Login cURL Call -" + ex.ToString();
                }

                string id = "";                    
                try
                {                        
                    response = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 'Web Extension 2');                        
                    await client.SendAsync(response).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                    {
                        string contents = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                            
                        //assign id value                        
                    });
                }                    
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    using (var tsw = new StreamWriter(path + "error.txt", true))
                    {
                        tsw.WriteLine("Error with Load Config cURL Call - " + ex.ToString() + "\r\n---------------------------------------------------");
                    }
                    result = "Error with Load Config cURL Call - " + ex.ToString();
                }
                if (id != "")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < allNumbers.Count; i++)
                    {                                              
                        try
                        {                                
                            file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + allNumbers[i] + ".xml");                                
                            response = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 'We Extension 3.1' + id + 'Web Extension 3.2');                                
                            response.Content = new StringContent(file, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");                                
                            await client.SendAsync(response).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                            {                                    
                            });                                
                        }                            
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            using (var stw = new StreamWriter(path + "error.txt", true))
                            {
                                stw.WriteLine("Error with Update cURL Call - " + ex.ToString() + "\r\n---------------------------------------------------");
                            }
                            result = "Error with Update cURL Call - " + ex.ToString();
                        }

                        try
                        {                                
                            file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "saveActivate.xml");                                
                            response = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 'Web Extension 4.1' + id + 'Web Extension 4.1');                                
                            response.Content = new StringContent(file, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

                            await client.SendAsync(response).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                            {                                    
                            });                                
                        }                            
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            using (var stw = new StreamWriter(path + "error.txt", true))
                            {
                                stw.WriteLine("Error with Save and Activate cURL Call - " + ex.ToString() + "\r\n---------------------------------------------------");
                            }
                            result = "Error with Save and Activate cURL Call - " + ex.ToString();
                        }

                        try
                        {                                
                            response = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 'Web Extension 5.1' + id + 'Web Extension 5.2');                                
                            await client.SendAsync(response).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                            {                                                                       
                                result = "Value update was a success!";                                    
                            });                                
                        }                            
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            using (var stw = new StreamWriter(path + "error.txt", true))
                            {
                                stw.WriteLine("Error with Load Config cURL Call - " + ex.ToString() + "\r\n---------------------------------------------------");
                            }
                            result = "Error with Load Config cURL Call - " + ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var tsw = new StreamWriter(path + "error.txt", true))
                    {
                        tsw.WriteLine("Error getting current SDM ID number.\r\n---------------------------------------------------");
                    }
                    result = "Error getting current SDM ID number.";
                }
            }
}
```

Here is the updated code for the Update() function.

Comment: Async void functions are not a good idea. If anything you should return a Task<T> from the async method and then use the keyword Await before the call to the method.

Comment: I've tried that then it only executes one of the curl calls and then just ends :/

Comment: Without any code for `Update()` it makes it difficult to help more.

Comment: It is quite long (about 200 lines), but I can add it if you think it could help. I have a descent amount of comments to make it easier to interpret.

Comment: I think the lines in `Update()` where it does the curl call would probably be sufficient for now.

Comment: Okay I have the function added to the question.

Comment: I don't see where you ever set id equal to anything but an empty string, then you have an if condition of `if(id != "")` do your loop of allNumbers, so it's no wonder you only get one call and then it returns.

Comment: It's inside the await section underneath where the id is created. There was a lof of code there but essentially it pulls a xml file from a curl call and then parses through it to get the id.

Comment: Have you set break points inside this method? Is it going inside your for loop if so, like I said previously, you should change the method signature to return a Task<T> and then call Await in your main method which calls this async method.

Comment: As soon as there really is something to await, the function returns. There should then be a Task to enable resuming the method. So return Task and await that

Comment: @RyanWilson your suggested worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your patience and assistance, this issue has been driving me crazy for a couple weeks now lol

Comment: @parrigin777 I'm glad I could help. It's always such a relief when you get something that has been troubling you for so long to work correctly. :)

Comment: @parrigin777 I added my suggestion as an answer below, as that is by SO's guidlelines.

Comment: @parrigin777 If you are happy with the information I provided, please mark my answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your async method to return a Task and then in your main method call await (your async method):

```
public async Task<T> Update(List<string> allNumbers, List<string> allValues)
```

In the Main method

```
await Update(allNumbers, allValues);
```

Comment: @parrigin777 You're welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have a non-async method call an async method?

Comment: @parrigin777 You can call an async method from a non-async method, but you will not be able to use the await keyword.

Comment: The issue I am running into now is my async method returns a Task<string> and I need a normal string. Is this achievable? I have also tried to just call the method and have it change a global string but the code using the global string executes before the async method changes the global string.

Comment: @parrigin777 You can use the returned Task `.Result` to get the returned string value. So for example, string responseString = await YourAsyncMethod().Result;